# How can I increase the size of the beamer navigation symbols?

Tags: beamer, navigation, accessibility

I am helping someone to create a `beamer` presentation and due to some physical disabilities, they would like to be able to use the `beamer` navigation symbols on a touchscreen to advance slides, rather than a keyboard or mouse. However, the navigation symbols are quite small and difficult to press accurately, so they would like to increase the size of the buttons. I've checked the documentation and other questions here on SE but I haven't been able to find any solutions. Is there a way to increase the size of the buttons or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

The template you are looking for is called `navigation symbols` and is defined in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty` through `\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{default}`. One approach is to create alternative symbols through a redefinition of `\insertslidenavigationsymbol` & Co. but something way simpler is to use an `adjustbox` for the whole thing and redefine it. An example to scale it to 80% of the `\paperwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\defbeamertemplate*{navigation symbols}{enlarged}
{%
    \adjustbox{min width=0.8\paperwidth}{%
        \hbox{%
            \hbox{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}
            \hbox{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
            \hbox{\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol}
            \hbox{\insertsectionnavigationsymbol}
            \hbox{\insertdocnavigationsymbol}
            \hbox{\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\frame{TEST}
\end{document}
```

In case visual impairment is an issue, you could also redefine the color of the elements to be more prominent, e.g. in `black` and a dark gray (`black!60`) by stating:

```
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=black!60}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=black}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Is ot possible to add this symbols in book class?

Comment: @ElijahOjiambo I suggest to ask a new question.